# Spreadsheet Pivot by row values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ms-office

I would like to Pivot on row values to get Counts for my below data.

[image]

Expecting output to look like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you should (or can ?) use Pivot.

[image]

Some formulas like these  should give needed values.
Note:

- `$F4` refers to the cell containing "Proficient"
- `$F5` refers to the cell containing "Enhusiast"
- `$F6` refers to the cell containing "Amateur"
- `A$2:A$10` refers to your data